# Two combinatorial identities: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}k2^{n-k}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-2} \binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have to compute the following quantity:

$$
1)    \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}k2^{n-k}
$$

Moreover, I have to give an upper bound for the following quantity:

$$
2)    \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-2} \binom{n}{k}\frac{k}{n-k}
$$

As regards 1), I see that  $\binom{n}{k}k2^{n-k}=\frac{n! (n-k+1)2^{n-k}}{(n-k+1)!(k-1)!}$, i.e. I obtain

$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n! (n-k+1)2^{n-k}}{(n-k+1)!(k-1)!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k-1}(n-k+1)2^{n-k}
$$

But it seems strange! As regards 2), I don't know!

Comment: For the first, you  will be better off using the fact  that if $k\ne 0$ then  $k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.  Now bring the $n$ outside and the answer should drop out.

Comment: But my sum goes from 0 to n. Actually, this sum what becomes?

Comment: Your sum does not really go from $0$ to $n$, since the $k=0$ term makes no contribution.

Comment: Dropping out $n$, I obtain $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}2^{n-k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n-1}{k}2^{n-k+1}$, am I right?

Comment: You should get $n\sum_1^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}2^{(n-1)-(k-1)}$. You may recognize the sum as the binomial expansion of $(1+2)^{n-1}$, so the whole thing is $n\cdot 3^{n-1}$.

Comment: Or reindex, $j=k-1$. The sum is $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{j}2^{(n-1)-j}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT for the first problem: $\binom{n}kk2^{n-k}$ is the number of ways to start with $n$ people, choose a team of size $k$, choose one of the team members to be captain, and then choose some subset of the remaining $n-k$ people to be substitutes. Thus, $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk2^{n-k}$ is the total number of ways to do this allowing the size of the team to be arbitrary.

You can bet the same effect by choosing one person from the $n$ to be captain, then dividing the remaining $n-1$ people into three groups: the other members of the team, the substitutes, and everyone else.

- How many ways are there to choose one person from the $n$ to be captain?
- How many ways are there to divide $n-1$ people into three sets, any of which can be empty?

Combine the answers to those two questions properly, and you’ll have a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk2^{n-k}$ as a function of $n$.

There are lots of possible upper bounds for the second summation. One, not especially good, can be obtained by noting that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n}k\frac{k}{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n}{n-k}=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-1}k\frac1{n-1-k}$$

and that $\frac1{n-1-k}\le 1$ for $k=0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: Only a question: in your answer, I think there is a little mistake, in fact $k \neq n-1$, otherwise the quantity $\frac{1}{n-k-1}$ tends to $\infty$. Since you have shifted of $-1$ the index of the sum, $n-1$ is not correct, it would be $n-3$

Comment: @Federico: You’re absolutely right: thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, $(x+2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k2^{n-k}$. Now differentiate in $x$:

$n(x+2)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}2^{n-k}.$

Now plug in $x=1$.

For the second one, $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$. Notice that:

$$\frac{(x+y)^n}{y}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k-1}.$$

Perform partial differentiation in $x$, *integrate* in $y$, and plug in $x,y=1$. Then correct for any boundary issues in the sum indices.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the combinatorial approach, but we can do it by manipulation. First note that our sum is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}\tag{1}$$
since the $k=0$ term makes no contribution to the sum.
Then use the fact that $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ to rewrite (1) as
$$n\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1}2^{n-k}.\tag{2}$$
Re-index the sum, replacing $k-1$ by $j$. Then (2) becomes
$$n\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{j}2^{n-1-j}.\tag{3}$$
We recognize the binomial expansion of $(1+2)^{n-1}$, so (3) is equal to 
$$n\cdot3^{n-1}.$$